# Is it possible to handle calls of a phone with a seperate device connected via bluetooth?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I was doing some research and wanted to know if it's possible to handle calls of my phone from a device (smart watch, bluetooth headset) that is connected to my phone via bluetooth.

I intend it be able to answer calls that come to phone and make calls from my phone when I give the command to the device and I want that device to act like the bluetooth speaker during the call.

I've seen use cases where it is done but have no idea on how it's done or where to start, Any ideas on this? :)

Comment: Yes it is possible. "Windows Your Phone" does the same thing.

Comment: @stillKonfuzed any idea on how its done? or a place to start?

Comment: @stillKonfuzed I also looked at "Windows your phone" , looks like it's syncing over internet?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is smartwatch with a speaker/microphone. You should be able to find plenty of them on [internet.](https://www.amazfit.com/en/)

Comment: I was referring to the programme inside of a smart watch :) I'm building my own